# Strip down google map jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is the code I am working with:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/9/

I am using googles geocoding service on my site What I would like to do is geocode an address including autocomplete. I have this working, except that it shows a map.

What I would like to do is strip out the map component on the code and instead display the map on the results page, which conforms to googles T&C.

So my question is, with the code posted above, how can I remove the code I don’t need to remove the map functionality?

**EDIT: This is how far I got before I got stuck!
http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/34/**

**EDIT2: This is all about I can comment out before it breaks:
http://jsfiddle.net/cNbkj/**

Comment: `#geomap{display:none;}` - CSS is all you need.

Comment: Yeah but thats a bit of a bodge. I mean the Javascript is doing all that work to display a map just so I can hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load the map in order to use the geocoder. Just remove your map div and comment out the following line:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("geomap"), options);
```

Please be aware the Google Maps Geocoding API is subject to the following [limit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits):

> "Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map;
>   geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For
>   complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of
>   Service License Restrictions."

Comment: Sorry but this seems wasteful. I dont want to call data which I just hide. I want to remove the map bit from the jquery but nobody on the net seems ot have any examples of this.

Comment: Further to your question, there will be a map on the second page and since I am also using autocomplete I will still conform with the T&C

Comment: Further to your edit - removing that line breaks the geocoding application.

Comment: You can use geocoder without a map. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/43/

Comment: Check the new version: http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/44/

Comment: Also take a look at your browser's JavaScript debugger tool (Firebug, F12 developer tools, etc.). They are priceless aids in JS development!

Comment: This is great, thank you...except! The results returned are different. Its returning addresses not co-ordinates

Comment: You can display *any properties* the geocoder results. Address was just an example. It's up to you what you want to print. See this final revision for the coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/Rr5PL/45/

Comment: If you want to see what the geocoder return just add command `console.log(results)` inside your geocoder callback function. If you don't know how to use console you should definitely learn it ASAP!

Comment: Thank you for the help. I want to wait though, because while you have helped, the solution you propose is very different to my one. For example, your solution prints out many answers, not one co-ordinate, it also prints out specific addresses rather than towns/cities and it also doesnt have the autosuggest functionality. I do appreciate your help but we are looking at two very different functionalities here.

Comment: Well I'm not going to write your code. What I proposed was *a proof of concept*. Translating that into your app code is called *work* and you hopefully get paid for doing that :)

Comment: I do appreciate the help, but the original question was to see what I can strip out. With your code it is pretty new and I dont understand it so I am not sure I can use it.

Comment: Ok fine, I commented out the map and removed the div, but that's as far as I'm gonna go here: http://jsfiddle.net/rK2pE/21/ If your question relates to some other aspect of this work, don't hesitate to open a new question!